# error when the screen is rotated during ProgressDialog

Tags: android

I starts the thread. with him ProgressDialog. everything works fine, but if runtime ProgressDialog, rotate the screen application gives an error. as well as how to make the ProgressDialog while nothing could be pressed until finished loading?

```
public static void openImage(final Context context, String link)
    {
        final ProgressDialog prog1 = new ProgressDialog(context);
        NewThread t = new NewThread();
        t.setOnParseResult(new IOnParseResult() {
            @Override
            public void onDone(ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> data, String linknew) {}

            @Override
            public void onImageLinkGet(Bitmap str, String url) {
                b = str;

                context.startActivity(new Intent(context, Photo.class));
                prog1.dismiss();
            }
        });
        prog1.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        prog1.setMessage("Идет загрузка");
        prog1.setIndeterminate(true);
        prog1.setCancelable(true);
        prog1.show();
        t.execute(link,"video");

    }


04-02 16:07:38.928: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(29411): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:153)
        at com.example.GoogleMemu.MyAdapter.<init>(MyAdapter.java:26)
        at com.example.GoogleMemu.MyActivity$PlanetFragment.addData(MyActivity.java:226)
        at com.example.GoogleMemu.MyActivity$2.onDone(MyActivity.java:123)
        at com.example.GoogleMemu.NewThread.onPostExecute(NewThread.java:101)
        at com.example.GoogleMemu.NewThread.onPostExecute(NewThread.java:22)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4464)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:822)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:589)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What error? A snippet from the logcat would help.

Comment: Do dialog.dismis() in the onPause method of the Activity (make it at class level for that). And you can set setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false) to avoid cancelling of Progress dialog when clicked on screen. However user can cancel it pressing BACK button as thats the desired behaviour and one shouldnt change that.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because when you are rotating your device, then OnCreate() is getting called  as there is a change in orientation, you should save your activity in order to prevent error.

Answer (score 0):

Override onConfigurationChanged() in your activity